# iphone add local access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios

if I download a html from my web server can i use an image in my iphone app's resource folder as background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just access it as such:

css:

`body{

background-image:url('filename.png');

...

}`